# SQL Query Multi record

Tags: sql, oracle

In an Oracle database, I have records like this:

```
Column A     Column B
---------------------
Test            R
Test            W
Test2           W
Test3           K
Test3           X
Test4           Y
```

only these records should be my output

```
Column A      Column B
-----------------------
Test            R
Test2           w
Test3           K
Test4           Y
```

I tried with query like:

```
select * 
from X.table 
where Column A = 'Test' and Column B = 'R';
```

how to implement for muti records?

Comment: What is the logic behind it?

Comment: In Oracle DB we have Test with R,W I want to display only record of Test matching with R and not W , the above query works for single record but how can I implement for multi records

Comment: **Typo alert**: it's a **column** (not a "coloumn")

Answer (score 0):

This will return the expected result:

```
select columnA, min(columnB)
from X.table
group by columnA
```

For each columnA value, return the lowest columnB value.

Comment: It is not related to lowest value

Comment: @Sandeep, Works fine with your sample data and expected result. Perhaps you could make some sample data changes, to describe the problem better?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with partition by I think (note: this is Oracle SQL):

```
select*
from
  (
  select x.*
        , row_number() over (partition by column_a order by column_b) rn 
  from x
  )
where rn =1;
```